# UITableView cell reuse identifier

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have created a structure for different Cell Identifiers:

```
enum CustomCellIdentifiers
{
    static let cellForCountry = "cellForCountry"
    static let cellForCity = "cellForCity"
    static let cellForStoreType = "cellForStoreType"
}
```

and I am registering the cell to the table as per switch case, like:

```
view.tableForItems.register(UINib.init(nibName: cellIdentifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier)
```

but when I registered the cell I got at error that the `reuseIdentifier` is nil:

```
 class CustomTableCell: UITableViewCell
    {
    override func awakeFromNib()
        {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // Initialization code
            switch self.reuseIdentifier ?? "cellForCountry" //It only work with country cell
{
            case CustomCellIdentifiers.cellForCountry:
                 print("cellForCountry") break;
            case CustomCellIdentifiers.cellForCity:
                 print("cellForCity")                break;
            case CustomCellIdentifiers.cellForStoreType:
                                print("cellForStoreType")
                break;
            default: break

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use enum instead of Struct if you want to store simple Strings and want it to be immutable. Also, there's no need for the breaks in the switch cases.

Comment: Instead of struct, use enum to store values.

Comment: @Jaydeep i changed but problem with reuse identifier is nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `reUseIdentifier` in the `xib` file too. 
if you are not able to set the reuseIdentifier in xib class means you created xib file from UIView. Instead 
Take the UITableviewcell Class to create xib not the UIView.. 
then you are able to assign reuseIdentifier from xib file

Please see the image below

[image]

Comment: So in the switchCase `switch self.reuseIdentifier` does none of the case is getting executed ?

Comment: How it worked with optional can you please share some details ?

Comment: Have you set the reuseIdentifier in xib file ?